# Can I deactivate CSS3 animations only in Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, css-transitions

Because my CSS3 animation uses over 50% of CPU in Chrome Browser 21.0 on MacOS X 10.7. But not in Safari (who uses Webkit too). In Firefox it works with low CPU as well.

The only way I see is to deactivate my animation in Chrome. Is there a way to do this? Maybe without Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect what browser visitor is using in server side. But i suggest You to do this with javascript:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```